# Limit number of items in ListView from Adapter

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

I currently am using a SimpleCursorAdapter with a ListView that pulls items using a CursorLoader from a ContentProvider and SQlite DB. The database contains around 300 items and I want to limit the number of its the Adapter passes the Listview so the ListView doesn't present all items from the Database. I want to avoid putting a limit on the db.query but rather hold items in the Adapter or limit the ListView. I haven't found an elegant solution to this. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - why are you trying to do this?

Comment: why don't you want to limit the db.query? what good is having data loaded into your adapter if you aren't going to show it in your AdapterView?

Comment: I am trying to do this to prevent my ListView from being 300 items long when created. I would like to have the data fetched by the adapter and have the ListView only display it when reaching end of visible items, for instance loading 25 items at a time. Similar to how Twitter displays ListView content. Hopefully that clarifies questions.

Comment: @Kyle You are misunderstanding how adapters and ListViews work. If you  make a query that returns 300 items for your Adapter and then only show 25 of those items you will still incur the performance hit for loading all 300. Whether or not Views(rows in your list) get made for the 275 other items is irrelevant. What you are trying to achieve would be using a query that loads 25, and then another query that loads another 25 and adds them to the current data when the user reaches the bottom. Not loading all 300 with one query and then limiting the view to show only 25 of them.

Comment: @FoamyGuy Can you provide an example of this query process?

Comment: @Kyle I don't think you need to worry about using this pattern. Loading a CursorAdapter with 300 items from a db should be relatively quick honestly. The pattern that you speak of is more useful when you are loading data from a webservice into a ListView rather than from a db file. If you are certain you want to do it anyway though I would say study the [EndlessAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) that Commonsguy created and try to modify that to fit your situation of loading from a db.

Comment: @Kyle : **"I am trying to do this to prevent my ListView from being 300 items long when created."** - Your `ListView` will never be 300 items long (unless you have a huge screen and very small text). A `ListView` displays list item views and there will only ever be as many of those item views as can fit on the screen. When an item is scrolled off the top or the bottom of the screen, it's view is recycled. Limiting the db query (or not) won't make a difference to "how long" the `ListView` is.

Answer (score 2):

Make a custom adapter, and override the getCount function to return min(actual_number, max_you_want);

Answer (score 1):

> The database contains around 300 items and I want to limit the number of its the Adapter passes the Listview so the ListView doesn't present all items from the Database.

Cursors are rather efficient and 300 is a relatively small number so you should be able to just fetch all 300 at once.  They are only drawn when the ListView scrolls.  So if you see slow performance the problem might be in rendering the rows, not the Cursor.

> I would like to have the data fetched by the adapter and have the ListView only display it when reaching end of visible items, for instance loading 25 items at a time.

This is simple enough consider a query like:

```
//db.query(tableName, columns, where, whereArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit);
int limit = 25;
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null, String.valueOf(limit));
```

When you hit the bottom of your ListView, add 25 more to `limit` and run the query again:

```
limit += 25;
cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null, String.valueOf(limit));
```

And so on, until `limit >= cursor.getCount()`.